# command 'pythonsetup.py egg_info' error code 1 when trying to install library

Tags: python, pip

I'm having trouble installing pyautogui, pyobjc, and pyobjc-core libraries on OSX. Here is the error I get:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-ns7p77pf/pyobjc-core
```

I tried updating pip and setup tools and I'm at a lost. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Install PIL first. If you're using Py3, install Pillow, a PIL substitute.